# Does "all morning" mean that the morning is over?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> 'I don't know. It _____ (4) (be) there all morning.' The man replied.'Well, we can't leave it there, it's too dangerous. He might have an accident. What should I do?' The cashier suggested, 'you should take it to the zoo.' 'That's a good idea,' the man said. 'I _____ (5) (take) him now

The answer for (4) is "was" but I think "has been" could do it because the penguin is still there even if it is not morning anymore (but this is not written in the text ).

The answer for (5) is "will take" but I  think "are taking"could do it because that is what  the man is doing very very soon  even if it is an instant decision .

What do you think of my suggestions? Are they possible with the context ?

https://www.esl-lounge.com/student/grammar/2g31-penguin-story.php

Comment: The title doesn't match what you actually ask. What are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most natural option (in my opinion) is "It's been there all morning". If the couple are going out for the day, it is presumably still morning. (If it is now afternoon, the cashier would say "It's been there all day.")

"I'll (I will) take him now" is by far the most likely choice. The man is accepting a suggestion ("That's a good idea"), not referring to a decision he has made.

PS I've just looked again at the website, and the suggested answer for (4) is indeed 'has been'.